# reload project after logging in in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Thank in advance for your response. I have a problem. I'm watching for user inactivity and logout after after a lapse of time. I have implemented it in my app.component.ts and it works just fine but only once, as when the app logs you out ngOnInit of app.component won't trigger again. I'am looking for a way to reload the page once you log in so the app.component.ts oninit would trigger and start watching my whole application.

I tried window.location.reload() but, when I write that in OnInit of my home component it keeps reloading the page (of course). Any way to reaload the window just once?

my app.component

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgZone, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ProvisionedService } from '../../devices/provisioned-list/provisioned.service';
import { UsersService } from '../../users/users.service';
import { fromEvent, merge, interval, Observable, of, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap, take, skipWhile, takeLast, skipUntil, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { FuseConfirmDialogComponent } from "@fuse/components/confirm-dialog/confirm-dialog.component";
import { MatDialogRef, MatDialog } from "@angular/material";
import { StorageService } from '../../common/services/storage.service';
import { AuthService } from '../../common/services/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  deviceList: DeviceModel[];
  devicesAlive: any;
  vanillaDevices: DeviceModel[];
  getDevicesInfoLoop: any;
  isAlive: any;
  invitationList: InvitationModel[];
  deviceId: any

  inactivityTime: number = 15;

  timeLapsedSinceInactivity: number = 0;
  seconds: number = this.padZero(0);
  subscription: Subscription;
  observeable$: Observable<any>;
  mergedObservable$: Observable<any>;
  event: Event;
  confirmDialogRef: MatDialogRef<FuseConfirmDialogComponent>;

  public inactivityTimerEvent: Array<any>[] = [[document, 'click'], [document, 'wheel'], [document, 'scroll'], [document, 'mousemove'],
   [document, 'keyup'], [window, 'resize'], [window, 'scroll'], [window, 'mousemove']];



  constructor(private provisionedService: ProvisionedService, private VanillaService: VanillaService, 
    private UsersService: UsersService, public _ngZone: NgZone,
    public _cd: ChangeDetectorRef,
    public matDialog: MatDialog,
    public storageService: StorageService,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    let observableArray$: Observable<any>[] = [];

    this.inactivityTimerEvent.forEach(x => {
      observableArray$.push(fromEvent(x[0], x[1]))
    })
    this.mergedObservable$ = merge(...observableArray$);

    this.startTimer(event);


  }

  public createObserable(): void {
    this._ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {

      this.observeable$ = this.mergedObservable$
      .pipe(
        switchMap(ev => interval(1000).pipe(take      (this.inactivityTime))),

        tap(value => this.isItTimeToShowPopUp(value)),

        skipWhile((x) => {
          this.timeLapsedSinceInactivity = x;
          return x != this.inactivityTime - 1
        })
      );

      this.subscribeObservable();
    })

  }

  public isItTimeToShowPopUp(val: number) {
    let timeLeftForInactive = this.inactivityTime - val;
    if (timeLeftForInactive <= 15) {

      this.timeLapsedSinceInactivity = timeLeftForInactive;
      this.seconds = this.padZero(timeLeftForInactive % 15);
      this._cd.detectChanges();
      console.log(timeLeftForInactive);
    }



    if(timeLeftForInactive === 1) {
      this.authService.removeUserData();
      this.storageService.removelocalStorageData();
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);

    }
    }



  public subscribeObservable() {
    this.subscription = this.observeable$.subscribe((x) => {
      console.log(`subscribed for ${x + 1} sec`);
      this.unsubscribeObservable()
    })
  }
  public padZero(digit: any) {
    return digit <= 9 ? '0' + digit : digit;
  }

  public unsubscribeObservable() {
    console.log('  unsubscriebd')
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  public startTimer($event) {
    this.createObserable();
    console.log('subscription started');
  }
  public stopTimer(event) {
    if (this.subscription && !this.subscription.closed) {
      this.seconds = this.padZero(0);
      this.unsubscribeObservable();
    }
  }


}
```

Comment: There is a lot of code here and it seems more complex than necessary. Also, you are obscuring your dependencies and making the solution far more difficult by using properties instead of parameters to such an extent.

Answer (score 0):

If it is needed to refresh a component without navigating to another component without using  window.location.reload()  or  location.reload(), we can use the following code in a project:

```
mySubscription: any; // declare the variable inside component class
```

Then, add this code to the required component's constructor.

```
this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = function () {
  return false;
};

this.mySubscription = this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
  if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
    // Trick the Router into believing it's last link wasn't previously loaded
    this.router.navigated = false;
  }
});
```

Make sure to unsubscribe  from this mySubscription  in  ngOnDestroy().

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  if (this.mySubscription) {
    this.mySubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Finally you can write your code for watching user inactivity inside ngOnInit. I used this technique in another purpose to refresh/reload the component and it worked in my case. You may need to reorganize your code based on your needs.